# How to query if a customer has gave a lower rating before?

Tags: sql

product(prod id, product name, product price, product manufacturer)

---

customer(cust id, customer name, customer address)

---

rating(prod id, cust id, rating date, rating stars)

> Foreign Key: prod id references prod id in product table
>
> Foreign Key: cust id references cust id in customer table

---

sale(sale id, prod id, cust id, sale quantity, sale cost)

> Foreign Key: prod id references prod id in product table
>
> Foreign Key: cust id references cust id in customer table

---

These schemas represent product information, including sales. Customers can provide ratings for products in a 0 to 5 stars fashion. It is possible for clients to rate the same product more than once.

And here is the question:

- For all cases in which the same customer rated the same product more
  than once, and in some point in time gave it a lower rating than
  before, return the customer name, the name of the product, and the
  lowest star rating that was given.

Is there a way to query customers that gave a lower rating **before**? thank you

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?  You won't get good at SQL if you don't try doing it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather tricky question.  But the answer to your question is `EXISTS`.  The following returns the pairs that have this behavior:

```
select r.cust_id, r.prod_id
from ratings r
where exists (select 1
              from ratings r2
              where r2.cust_id = r.cust_id and
                    r2.prod_id = r.prod_id and
                    r2.date < r.date and
                    r2.stars < r.stars
             )
```

Alas, this does not return the minimum stars (because nothing will be before it).  One trick is to invert the logic -- so select any rating that has a *higher* rating following it.  The minimum will meet this criterion, so you can do:

```
select r.cust_id, r.prod_id, min(r.stars)
from ratings r
where exists (select 1
              from ratings r2
              where r2.cust_id = r.cust_id and
                    r2.prod_id = r.prod_id and
                    r2.date > r.date and
                    r2.stars > r.stars
             )
group by r.stars;
```

I'll let you add the `JOIN`s to get the names.